# Criar um ficheiro bath que realize o DIR de uma pasta ou conjuntos de pastas que o utilizador escolha

Tags: batch, ms-dos

Queria criar um ficheiro em `bath` onde o utilizador escolhesse o local onde realizar o comando `DIR`.

Eu tenho isto feito:

```
@echo off

set /p pasta=digite uma pasta: dir %pasta%>>c:\conteudo2.txt

if exist %pasta% goto existe

if not exist %pasta% goto nao

:existe

echo file found

goto fim

:nao

echo file not found

:fim pause
```

O meu problema é esse:

> " Crie a partir da linha de comandos um ficheiro com o nome Listar2.bat, que permita guardar dentro de um ficheiro com o nome Conteudo2.txt, no ambiente de trabalho, o conteúdo de um diretório fornecido pelo user. "

Comment: Explique melhor como você quer que seja feita essa escolha, e mostre o que você já tem pronto. Senão a pergunta fica ampla demais para o formato deste site (dê uma olhada no [tour]).

Comment: Por que excluir a pergunta, @LaércioLopes?

Answer (score 0):

Seu código está correto, só precisa pular a linha antes do comando `dir` e do `pause`.

Ficando assim:

```
@echo off

set /p pasta=digite uma pasta:

dir %pasta%>>c:\conteudo2.txt

if exist %pasta% goto existe

if not exist %pasta% goto nao

:existe

echo file found

goto fim

:nao

echo file not found

:fim

pause
```

Comment: Não é mais fácil usar `dir [caminho]` direto? Pra que o batch nesse caso?

Comment: Verdade né? mas ela quer um batch...

Comment: A pergunta não está clara. Pode ser que ela queira isso, pode ser que queira algo bem mais complexo como o midnight commander.

Comment: Pra mim parece bem clara apesar de ser muito simples.

Comment: Não estou entendendo esses seus pedidos de excluir a pergunta.

Comment: Por acreditar que dificilmente essa pergunta ajudará outros usuários.

Answer (score 0):

deixo aqui o meu script ...

```
@echo off
mode 70,8
:main

echo.&echo. Arraste uma pasta e dˆ enter.
set /p caminho=^>:

if not defined caminho (cls &goto main)
set caminho=%caminho:"=%
if not exist "%tmp%\Lista-dir" (md "%tmp%\Lista-dir")

cls
echo.&echo. Escolha uma Op‡Æo: &echo.

echo. [1] - Listar somente pastas
echo. [2] - Listar somente pastas e Subpastas
echo. [3] - Listar pastas, Subpastas e arquivos.

CHOICE /c "123" /n /M:

if %errorlevel% equ 1 (dir /b "%caminho%">%tmp%\Lista-dir\listagem.txt)
if %errorlevel% equ 2 (tree /a "%caminho%">%tmp%\Lista-dir\listagem.txt)
if %errorlevel% equ 3 (tree /a /f "%caminho%">%tmp%\Lista-dir\listagem.txt)

explorer %tmp%\Lista-dir\listagem.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

type nul >"%userprofile%\desktop\conteudo2.txt" & set /p "_pasta=digite uma pasta: "  

2<nul dir "!_pasta!" | find ".." >nul || goto :_nao

:_existe
rem :: copia p/ seu "Crtl+c" o conteudo do arquivo "%userprofile%\desktop\conteudo2.txt"
dir !_pasta!>>"%userprofile%\desktop\conteudo2.txt" && clip < "%userprofile%\desktop\conteudo2.txt"
echo file found & goto :_fim

:_nao
echo file not found

:_fim
echo/Pressione qualquer tecla para continuar. . . && timeout /t -1 >nul
```